# friendly ids with overriding to param method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am overriding "to param" method for user model. And i'm also replacing controller find methods. Is there a problem with doing this? Everything seems working now.

User model

```
def to_param
 name
end
```

users_controller

```
@user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
```

Comment: Instead of using the auto-generated id, are you intending to use name as your primary key for the User model?

Comment: I guess yes. I do this for scaffolded models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend taking these steps:

- Make sure the name is unique.
- Make sure the primary_key of the User model is 'name' and not 'id' (User.primary_key). Many gems and modules depend on this value being correct. If it's not you might run into hard-to-debug issues later on.
- Take a look at the 'set_primary_key' declaration for ActiveRecord. It might be a simpler way to accomplish what you are doing.

In general it's totally fine to have a primary key that is something other than id. It's more difficult when this primary key isn't auto-generated, so take care with this and make sure you can [properly set this attribute](http://roninonrails.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-non-standard-primary-keys-with.html) and check that it is unique.